# How to write UNIX file-system "ls -R /" utility using modern C++11/C++14/C+1Z?

Tags: c++11, recursion, composite, boost-filesystem, c++17

To learn/understand the various concepts of modern C++, I tried to write similar program like "ls -R /" which would recursively lists sub directories. To achieve this I am using the **future C++ TS filesystem library** so that program could be portable. So far I am able to write the below program to achieve this.

```
#include<filesystem>
//Other herader files
// Below typedef is for VS2013
using fspath        = std::tr2::sys::path;
using dir_iterator  = std::tr2::sys::directory_iterator;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;

struct directory {
    std::vector<fspath> files;
    std::vector<fspath> operator()(const fspath& input) {
        std::cout << "Input Directory Name: " << input.string() << std::endl;
        dir_iterator bgnitr(input);
        dir_iterator enditr;
        for (dir_iterator itr = bgnitr; itr != enditr; ++itr) {
            // Only store the directory from input directory, 
            // otherwise display the name
            fspath tmp = *itr;
            if (is_directory(tmp)) {
                files.push_back(tmp);
            }
            else {
                tmp = tmp.filename();
                std::cout << tmp.string() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    fspath input{argv[1]};
    directory dir;
    auto files = dir(input);
    std::sort(std::begin(files), std::end(files));
    std::for_each(std::begin(files), std::end(files), directory());
    return 0;
}
```

The above program works fine and produce the expected result if my input directory has **one level of sub-directory**. I could have used the *"recursive_directory_iterator"*, but it gives the list of all files within all directory inside the input directory.

It does not handle the scenario where actual input directory contains the sub-directory which itself contains sub-directory and files. Basically these level can be upto any level which gets handled by UNIX "ls -R " utility.

## Question

I would like to know that whats could be next approach to handle the **n level** of hierarchy in the directory?

In general whats sort of approaches we should follow when we need to model/design similar things where **"part-whole hierarchies(recursive)**" needs to model. I am little bit aware about the ["composite design pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) which can be used to model such stuff. Could this pattern be applied in this particular problem?. If yes, could someone provide explanation/comment?

My main intention over here is to understand general guideline to handle such problem using modern C++ concepts/library/design concepts.Kindly let me know in case someone require any information on this.

Comment: There's no TR2. The TRs were abandoned some time ago. Now we have *Technical Specifications*, many of them, and each of which is focusing on one specific subject. You are looking for the [Filesystem TS](https://github.com/cplusplus/filesystem-ts) (which is currently being voted on).

Comment: How does this differ over any other recursive file-search implementation?

Comment: I have trouble understanding the question. Are you asking for a recursive list of files *up to a certain depth*, like with unix' find command's `-maxdepth`  option? That seems to be not too difficult with a second int parameter indicating the desired search depth which would be decremented for recursice calls.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes I am using Filesystem TS which you have referred.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I want to implement "ls -R inputdirectory" like utility using modern c++. This is just to understand/apply various concepts of C++ and design patterns and not to replace any UNIX utility. I hope you got my intention.

Comment: I understand that `ls -R` outputs the relative path of each directory found below the specified directory path, each time followed by a flat list of all the files and directories in it. I assume that you want to preserve that output structure; that's why the recursive_directory_iterator wouldn't work (it would not group the files nicely by directory).-- Seems like the prototypical application for a recursive approach (let your nice function call itself for each directory found). Anything wrong with that?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Yes you got the point what i am trying to achieve. Yes I am struggling and not able to thing the recursive approach and how it can be used in this particular case.

Comment: Nice that I got it :-).-- Recursion can be mind-boggling; it's trivial but hard to grasp at the same time. My tip: Find a tutorial about recursion and try it with something as simple as possible (classic example: compute the faculty of a number, or a recursive sorting algorithm). With directories there are too many distracting technicalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rename your `directory` class, it doesn't model a directory, it is a function that prints the contents of a directory.

You can use a range-based `for` loop with a `directory_iterator` to make the syntax simpler:

```
for (auto f : fs::directory_iterator{dir})
```

Your program assumes it will only be called with a single argument that refers to a directory, whereas `ls -R` can be called with zero or more arguments that are files or directories.

I would do it like this, although this could probably be improved to simplify the logic in `main` and incorporate it into the `ls` function:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

void ls(std::ostream& out, const fs::path& dir)
{
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, bool>> files;
  for (auto f : fs::directory_iterator{dir})
    files.emplace_back(f.path().filename(), is_directory(f));
  std::sort(files.begin(), files.end());

  // print directory contents
  out << dir.string() << ":\n";
  for (auto& f : files)
    out << f.first << '\n';
  out << std::endl;

  // recurse into directories
  for (auto& f : files)
    if (f.second)
      ls(out, dir / f.first);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    ls(std::cout, ".");
  else
  {
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    std::vector<std::string> dirs;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
      if (fs::is_directory(argv[i]))
        dirs.push_back(argv[i]);
      else
        files.push_back(argv[i]);
    std::sort(files.begin(), files.end());
    for (auto& f : files)
      std::cout << f << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::sort(dirs.begin(), dirs.end());
    for (auto& d : dirs)
      ls(std::cout, d);
  }
}
```